# Recipient error while using MessageBird SMS API in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sms, messagebird

I am trying to send message on the mobile number using `Messagebird` but getting the following error:

```
statusCode: 422,
  errors: [
    {
      code: 9,
      description: 'no (correct) recipients found. Note: during your test period you can only send messages 
to your own number (+).',
      parameter: 'recipient'
    }
  ]
```

The code is given below:

```
const messagebird = require('messagebird').initClient('2nAHkmfpX6kmgduCTz4cKDobe');
const originator = "SMSAPI";
const recipient = "+91XXXXXXXXXX";
const params = {
    originator: originator,
    recipients: [recipient],
    body: 'Hello, this is a test message from MessageBird!'
  };
  
  messagebird.messages.create(params, function (err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
```